# How to exclude services wired in @SpringBootApplication from @WebMvcTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot

If I have a spring boot class like the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    final FoService foService;

    public DemoApplication(FoService foService) {
        this.foService = foService;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and the following test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = FoController.class, secure = false)
public class FoControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void getFo() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/fo/"))

            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
}
```

The test fails on account of not being able to find `FoService`. I can add:

```
@MockBean
private FoService foService;
```

to the test. Or add  new spring boot application in test source tree, that doesn't wire the service, and test would start working.

My question is, is there another alternative, maybe using `excludeFilters` property?

In reality I have several services wired from the main spring boot application, and i wouldn't like to mock them all. Also, creating a test spring boot application is feeling more like a workaround.

Comment: Yes, you can use excludeFilters to ignore beans or packages. Just make sure that your target beans does not depend on the excluded ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy, do not add anything to your Main application class. Any Spring Boot Test, or Slice test like `WebMvcTest` will use and try to load any Bean or meta annotation with in it. E.g. any `@Enable..`.

You would be better served to move your beans to a `Configuration` class and keep the Main applicaiton with only `SpringBootApplication` and the main method.

Comment: yes, simple and effective. I've delegated the beans from `@SpringBootApplication` to a separate configuration. I had to take care that the some other configurations are loaded first. Still, definitely I feel most comfortable with this solution. The two other alternatives are to mock wired services from boot application in a controller test focused on a single controller, or to create a separate SpringBootApplication that doesn't autowire anything, and reference it from the test. However, this feels like the most correct approach

Answer (score 0):

Below should work..if you will run to load particulate controller then all dependency have to be mocked.`@AutoConfigureMockMvc` should work for your case.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void getFo() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/user"))

                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
}
```

Comment: yes, but I wanted to take advantage of what the `@WebMvcTest` gives me. At the end, I went for creating a test specific Spring Boot config that doesn't autowire any services. With this, I need to mock only the services used directly in the controller. Tahnks kj007